# jsp and servlet problems

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am using eclipse to make a connection between a jsp file and a servlet
I am trying to create servlet `com.example.servlet.MyServlet` , and a I have got a simple jsp code `search.jsp` in the WebContent 
the jsp code is some thing linke this

```
<form method = "post" action = "MyServlet">
<br><label for="title">Title</label>

<input type="textbox" name="title" value="" /></br>
<br><label for="auther">Auther</label>
<input type="textbox" name="auther" value="" /></br>
<br><label for="date">Date</label>
<input type="textbox" name="date" value="" /></br>
<br><label for="subject">Subject</label>
<input type="textbox" name="subject" value="" /></br>
<br><input type="submit" name = "search" value ="search" align="center"></br>
</form>
```

MyServlet is known in the `web.xml` file , but when I run the program it gives

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class com.journal.servlet.SearchServlet or a class it depends on
```

and

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.journal.servlet.SearchServlet
```

I cannot figure out what is the problem since I think every thing is in its right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says it can not find `com.journal.servlet.SearchServlet` class and You have mentioned that you have servlet at `com.example.servlet.MyServlet`

The compiled `.class` file must end up in `/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/servlet/MyServlet.class`.

So, Based on mentioned scenario in your post. altering associated `<servlet-class>` entry in `web.xml` should work.

Also Check

```
Project>Build Automatically
```

maybe you accidentally disabled the auto-deploy features.

Answer (score 0):

Your `web.xml` file should have

**Servlet location**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

**servlet mapping**

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

the console shows that your package is `com.journal.servlet....` NOT this `com.example.servlet...` make sure you have defined your package correctly. So rename your package